# Extracting the max consecutive missing values between the first and last value within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that has columns which start on different dates:

```
| Date       | Hour  | A | B | C | D |
--------------------------------------
| 01/01/2012 | 01:00 |   | 1 | 2 |   |
| 01/01/2012 | 03:00 |   |   |   | 1 |
| 01/01/2012 | 07:00 |   | 5 |   |   |
| 15/04/2012 | 01:00 | 1 |   | 2 | 3 |
| 16/01/2013 | 05:00 | 1 | 1 |   |   |
```

I want to extract the information on the number of consecutive missing values excluding that of the records outside of the first and last entry for each column. I am currently using:

```
df['Consecutive'] = df.Count.groupby((df.Count != df.Count.shift()).cumsum()).transform('size') * df.Count
```

When df's looks like:

```
| A | Count |
-------------
|   | True  |
|   | True  |
|   | True  |
| 1 | False |
| 1 | False |
```

Here Max Consecutive should be 0 (Currently above statement would get Max Consecutive as 3)
or

```
| D | Count |
-------------
|   | True  |
| 1 | False |
|   | True  |
| 3 | False |
|   | True  |
```

Here Max Consecutive should be 1
etc

To get the consecutive missing rows but I can't figure out how to exclude the areas outside the data collection range.

I believe I either need to calculate within the start and end range or delete the starting and ending blank records, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need:

```
print (df)
         Date   Hour    A    B    C    D
0  01/01/2012  01:00  NaN  1.0  2.0  NaN
1  01/01/2012  03:00  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
2  01/01/2012  07:00  NaN  5.0  NaN  NaN
3  15/04/2012  01:00  1.0  NaN  2.0  3.0
4  16/01/2013  05:00  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
5  01/01/2012  01:00  NaN  1.0  2.0  NaN
6  01/01/2012  03:00  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
7  01/01/2012  07:00  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8  15/04/2012  01:00  1.0  NaN  2.0  3.0
9  16/01/2013  05:00  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN

df = df.set_index(['Date','Hour'])
m = df.ffill().isnull() | df.bfill().isnull()
a = (df.isnull() & ~m)
b = a.cumsum()
c = (b-b.mask(a).ffill().fillna(0)).max()
print (c)
A    3.0
B    3.0
C    2.0
D    2.0
dtype: float64
```

**Detail**:

```
print (a)
                      A      B      C      D
Date       Hour                             
01/01/2012 01:00  False  False  False  False
           03:00  False   True   True  False
           07:00  False  False   True   True
15/04/2012 01:00  False   True  False  False
16/01/2013 05:00  False  False   True   True
01/01/2012 01:00   True  False  False   True
           03:00   True   True   True  False
           07:00   True   True   True   True
15/04/2012 01:00  False   True  False  False
16/01/2013 05:00  False  False  False  False
```

**Explanation**:

1. First create boolean mask with `forward` and `back filling` `NaN`s for exclude first and last values
2. Then count each `True`s consecutive values per columns and get `max`

Comment: @MaskedMonkey - You are welcome, it was very nice problem and I really like solve it.

Comment: Just investigating how its working further, is .fillna(0) needed as it seems to not change the answer in any way

Comment: @MaskedMonkey - So be free omit it :)